# Creating middleware function with dependency in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am using *ASP.NET Core v1.1* to create a WebSocket server. This is a striped down version of my **Startup.cs**:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
  // ...

  // route of "/ws" requests
  app.Map("/ws", Map);
}


public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  // add the db service
  services.AddDbContext<ArticleContext>(
    opts => opts.UseNpgsql("MyConnectionString")
  );
}

private void Map(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  app.UseWebSockets();
  app.Use(Acceptor);
}

private async Task Acceptor(HttpContext httpContext, Func<Task> next)
{
    // Handle the request using: httpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest
    // ...
}
```

As you can see I am using an **Acceptor** task to handle the web socket requests. I also add a **DbContext** in the **ConfigureServices** method.

I do not add any MVC functionality since I am not using it. But I need to access the **ArticleContext** to connect to my database.

All examples that I have seen are using a **Controller** that comes with the MVC packages. In such a controller you can inject the **DBContext** using constructor dependency injection.

I do not use a **Controller** but the **Acceptor** method so how do I get the **ArticleContext** instance there?

Do I somehow have to write a **MyAcceptor** class and add it to the app via **app.Use()** instead of using **app.Map** to be able to inject dependencies? .. just a guess.

Comment: did you know that you can add any dependencies you need to the Configure method signature and they will be injected into the method so long as they were registered in ConfigureServices?

Comment: No I did not know it. Can be useful but does not solve my issue. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to resolve the `ArticleContext` from the `HttpContext.RequestServices` property as follows:

```
private async Task Acceptor(HttpContext httpContext, Func<Task> next)
{
    var context = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ArticleContext>();
    // Handle the request using: httpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest
    // ...
}
```

You can also wrap the `Acceptor` method into a class of its own. In that case you can inject the `ArticleContext` into the constructor of that `AcceptorMiddleware` class, but this doesn't seem needed in your case.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I searched for. I wonder why I did not find such an example. Thank you Steven! I will try that as soon as possible.